# Rename file to folder path

Tags: bulk, renaming

I'm trying to rename files within thousands of folders to the folder path

So the file **123.jpg** in **C:\ABC\123.jpg** needs to be renamed to **ABC_123.jpg**

Whats the simplest way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your language... take folders/file names in as a string. parse through it example: `string[] lines = folders.split('\')`. Then use the spot with the ABC to concatenate it to the files string.